# C++ assign void pointer an string

Tags: c++

I have the next problem. I have a function like this.

unsigned long FuncTest(void* name) { ... }

When I call FuncTest, I'll make of this form

```
int main()
{

    void* test = NULL;

    cout << "Value of test before to call Function: " << test << endl;

    FuncTest(test);

    cout << "Value of test after to call Function: " << test << endl;
}
```

I need it that FuncTest change value of variable name for something like string o char. It is possible?

I put the code that I have it, but is not working.

```
void FuncTest(void* name)
{
    char* NewValue = _strdup("Hello!");
    cout << "Value of name in FuncTest before change: " << name << endl;

    name = NewValue;

    cout << "Value of NewValue in FuncTest: " << NewValue << endl;
    cout << "Value of name in FuncTest after change: " << (char*)name << endl;
}
```

The Result is the next:

```
Value of test before to call Function: 00000000
Value of name in FuncTest before change: 00000000
Value of NewValue in FuncTest: Hello!
Value of name in FuncTest after change: Hello!
Value of test after to call Function: 00000000
```

Somebody Can help me
Thanks!

Comment: If you called the function like this `FuncTest(NULL);` (which is obviously perfectly legal), would you expect that `NULL` to somehow change?

Comment: As dbush already correctly answered, this is indeed possible. I wonder _why_ would you do this?

Comment: I am trying to make a DLL that is consumed by another application. I have no control of that application. In the specifications of this application, it says that this parameter normally comes as void NULL, but that a value can be returned as C-string so that the application can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to change the value of test then just pass the pointer of test as a parameter of FuncTest function.

```
FuncTest(&test);
```

And FuncTest needs to be changed like this

```
void FuncTest(void** name)
{
    char* NewValue = _strdup("Hello!");
    cout << "Value of name in FuncTest before change: " << name << endl;

    *name = NewValue;

    cout << "Value of NewValue in FuncTest: " << NewValue << endl;
    cout << "Value of name in FuncTest after change: " << (char*)*name << endl;
}
```

If you are going to change the value of parameter then you should send an address. test seems pointer but it is registered in stack register when function is called. And stack register variables are initialized after function executes. So you need to send pointer of test then even it's freed after function ends, the value will be remained.
Hope this helps you to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You passed `test` to the function by value, so any change you make to it inside of the function won't be reflected in the calling program.

You need to pass it by reference:

```
void FuncTest(void *&name)
```

Comment: If this seems funny to you, remember that the object a pointer points at is passed by reference. The pointer itself is just an addresses and that address is passed by value. This is only marginally different from passing in an `int`, modifying it, and expecting the changed value at the other side.